# Argument passed through Function causing an error in the build

Tags: c

Greetings Stack Overflowians!

I'm having a tad bit of an issue here. There's this argument which I'm trying to pass, originally it is a Global Variable which does change in the main and I'm passing that variable as an argument for a function so it may change its behavior.

Here's the error message :

```
:: warning: (1273) Omniscient Code Generation not available in Free mode
mcc_generated_files/eusart1.c:94: warning: (520) function "_EUSART1_is_tx_ready" is never called
mcc_generated_files/eusart1.c:99: warning: (520) function "_EUSART1_is_rx_ready" is never called
mcc_generated_files/eusart1.c:104: warning: (520) function "_EUSART1_is_tx_done" is never called
mcc_generated_files/eusart1.c:109: warning: (520) function "_EUSART1_get_last_status" is never called
mcc_generated_files/eusart1.c:113: warning: (520) function "_EUSART1_Read" is never called
mcc_generated_files/eusart1.c:132: warning: (520) function "_EUSART1_Write" is never called
mcc_generated_files/eusart1.c:141: warning: (520) function "_getch" is never called
mcc_generated_files/eusart1.c:146: warning: (520) function "_putch" is never called
mcc_generated_files/pin_manager.c:92: warning: (520) function "_PIN_MANAGER_IOC" is never called
main.c:38321: error: (800) undefined symbol "__delay$0"
main.c:38326: error: (800) undefined symbol "__delay"
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:211: recipe for target 'dist/default/production/chasseur_de_led.X.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/projedct/chasseur_de_led_e/chasseur_de_led.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:90: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/chasseur_de_led_e/chasseur_de_led.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/chasseur_de_led.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

The part of the code I'm about to show does work but it's simply to give a tad bit of background info.

```
int niveau;
void sequence(int vitesse);        // Verifie l'etat de B0 pour changer le nieau

void main(void)                                                
{
    SYSTEM_Initialize(); 
    
    vie = 3;
    lumiere = 0;
    
    attente_joueur();   //En attente que le joueur lance la partie (B0)  
    
    niveau = 300;       //Le niveau 1 ccommence au niveau facile (300ms)
        do      
        {
           sequence(niveau);          //Lancement du  300, 150 ou 75 
           eteindre_les_lumieres();   //On éteint les lumières
           niveau = niveau /2;
        } while ((vie !=0) && (niveau >=75 ));
```

Niveau is basically the level. Every time the following function finishes, it goes back in here and it proceeds to change a few settings. (It's a game where a light keeps on blinking and they have to hit a switch at the right light)

Now now... Here's the troublemaker :

```
void sequence(int vitesse)
{
    int niveau_complete = 0;
    int tentative = 0;
    do
    {
        __delay_ms(1000);
        lumiere = 0;
        tentative=0;
        while(tentative!=1)
        {
            if (lumiere==8)
            {
                changement_de_lumiere();
                lumiere=0;
            }
            else 
            {
                lumiere++;
                changement_de_lumiere();
            }
            **__delay_ms(vitesse);**            
            eteindre_les_lumieres();
```

__delay_ms() is a command that's been often used in the project I've been working on.
Everything related to that specifically does work. So does the rest of the code. If I put an actual number say 300 instead of vitesse for __delay_ms() it works fine. But, that would defeat the purpose of making the game harder as the player progresses.

So here it is, trying to pass the value and trying to see how exactly it'd work. Never had this kind of problem previously so I'm a bit at a loss.

Thanks people!

Comment: Try running your code through just the preprocessor, both with `__delay_ms(vitesse);` and `__delay_ms(300);` and see how it differs.

Comment: __delay_ms(300) for instance does make it so there's that amount of miliseconds in-between the lights flicking on and off. So that does work.

__delay_ms(vitesse) though... nothing's coming out of it.

Comment: What I mean is run your source code through the preprocessor (which gcc it's the -E option) and look at the resulting source code, specifically where ` __delay_ms`.  The linker output states that it can't find `__delay` but that function isn't listed in the code you've shown, which leads me to believe `__delay_ms` is getting translated to that via the preprocessor.  You say that calling this function with an `int` variable fails to compile but calling it with an integer constant does, so I would suspect the preprocessor output where ` __delay_ms` is called differs in the two cases.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how to do that. I'm currently using MPLAB X IDE v5.10
And yeah, that specific function isn't there (__delay_ms). It's somewhere else in the project. 

(It's a school project)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I managed to find 
```
#define __delay_ms(x) _delay((unsigned long)((x)*(_XTAL_FREQ/4000.0)))
```

But aside of that, I'd have to give the whole project to give a minimal reproducible example